# Python Itertools Best Logic

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I am fairly new to python (~ 6 months) and extremely new to itertools. I'm hoping to find some guidance on the best/fastest itertools function to use for a process (doesn't have to be itertools but seems like that's the best bet through my research). I'm planning to stack many loops above and below the function so trying to keep it concise...

I have a list of symbols in a specific order and each symbols is assigned a list of unique numbers via dictionary - unique in the sense that no symbol will have the same number as another symbol and the numbers will not repeat. I need to generate a list of all unique combinations of each symbol's subset of numbers.

See example below:

Input list:
RI, WH, RI, FA

Input dictionary:
{RI: [1,2], WH: [3,4,5], FA: [6]}

Output:
 - 1,3,1,6
 - 2,3,2,6
 - 1,4,1,6
 - 2,4,2,6
 - 1,5,1,6
 - 2,5,2,6

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
from itertools import product

data = {'RI': [1,2], 'WH': [3,4,5], 'FA': [6]}
inp = ['RI', 'WH', 'RI', 'FA']
lists = [data[x] for x in inp]

print list(product(*lists))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 3, 1, 6),
 (1, 3, 2, 6),
 (1, 4, 1, 6),
 (1, 4, 2, 6),
 (1, 5, 1, 6),
 (1, 5, 2, 6),
 (2, 3, 1, 6),
 (2, 3, 2, 6),
 (2, 4, 1, 6),
 (2, 4, 2, 6),
 (2, 5, 1, 6),
 (2, 5, 2, 6)]
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted but that's not what he specified as expected result!

Comment: Also please don't encourage such 0-effort questions by providing answers.

Comment: Thanks, this is very close but not exactly there. I need the numbers for each abbreviation to be the same for any given output list. i.e., a single list should never contain both 1 and 2 or both 3 and 4. This should result in half of the number of output lists. Thanks again for the help @Μseifert